# Laravel 7 Notifications & AJAX: Method markAsRead() does not update results on return

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, notifications, laravel-7

I am implementing a dropdown menu with Database Notifications from Laravel's 7 Notifications. I want the user to be able to dismiss a notification without having to reload the page. My controller method is:

```
public function markAsRead($id) {
  auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->where('id', $id)->markAsRead();

  $notificationArray = array();
    $user = Auth::user();
    foreach ($user->unreadNotifications as $notification) {
        $notificationArray[] = $notification;
    }

  return view("layouts/notifications_list", ["notifications" => compact("notificationArray")]);
}
```

My AJAX :

```
$.ajax({
     method: "GET",
     url: ' {{ route('notifications.markNotificationAsRead', ['id']) }}'.replace('id', notificationId),
     cache: false,
      success: function(response) {
         $('#notifications-dropdown').empty();
         $('#notifications-dropdown').html(response);

     },
  });
```

What I get is the **already** rendered values. It is like the line `auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->where('id', $id)->markAsRead();`  is being ignored.
However, when I refresh the page the list is updated.

Comment: What does your route look like? `' {{ route('...` might have a space too much. As always, use your browser's DevTools/console/Network tab to make sure you get no errors/post to the correct url

Comment: The function is being called no problem. I used dd to doublecheck. The problem is that the list returned is the old one, as if no changes were made. After a redirection the correct results are shown

Comment: Could be an issue with dom updation. Check the response of the ajax call in the network tab of browser devtools or by console.log(response) in the success function and see whether the response contains the notification record for which the ajax request was made

Comment: @Donkarnash Indeed, this is the problem I am facing. While obviously markAsRead() works, it does not return the expected output.

Comment: What happens if you try `$notificationsArray = $user->fresh()->unreadNotifications->all()` instead of the foreach. Also check the whether the record with the $id received as route parameter exists in $notificationsArray using dd()

Comment: Same behaviour. ID exists in table. It seems like it has to have a redirection.